# R changing character to numeric

Tags: r

I'm new to R and for an assignment I need the sum of my data to equal 15. Here is the code I have tried, but I'm not sure how to change it from character to numeric.

`data <- c(rep("TRUE",10),rep("FALSE",10),rep("TRUE",5))`

I have tried using the `as.numeric(data)` function but am not sure what to do. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Don't use quotes.  Just try `data <- c(rep(TRUE,10),rep(FALSE,10),rep(TRUE,5))`    Then you should be able to use `sum(data)`  and get the desired result.

Comment: This is strange, normally `TRUE` and `FALSE` are used without quotes so that they are of the `logical` data type (which converts nicely to numeric). Since you use quotes, they are `character`, which doesn't convert easily to numeric. Maybe try `as.numeric(as.logical(data))` -- assuming you want the standard `TRUE` is 1, `FALSE` is 0. Or just leave out the quotes when you define your input.